# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "‘" when expecting one of the following: ( )

Tags: sql, triggers

I have a problem with my sql code. I try co create a trigger which will sum how much I earned after 'closing' the excursion. By closing I mean update a row and type there charge (payment), date and time.

Here's the table:

```
create table Excursion(
excIDExcursion NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY ,
excStartDate date not null,
excStartTime varchar(5) not null, 
excEndDate date,
excEndTime varchar(5),
excpayment number(8),
cIDCustomer number(4) references Customer,
ID_TaxiCab number(4) references TaxiCab
);
```

And here is this trigger which has an errors:

```
create or replace trigger HowMuchWeEarned
after update on Customer
for each row
declare sumofearning number;
begin
if(excendtime!='' and exceenddate!=null)
then
Select sum(excpayment) into sumofearning from Excursion;
dbms_output.put_line(‘We’ve earned’||sumofearning);
end;
/
show errors;
```

The error shows this:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "‘" when expecting one of the f ollowing: ( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> table c ontinue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading trailing forall mer ge year month day hour minute second timezone_hour timezone_mi nute timezone_region timezone_abbr time timestamp interval dat e <a string literal with character set specificatio
```

Probably there is a problem with this if statement, but I can't find out what is wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is smart quotes.  Try replacing with regular single quotes.  So, replace this line:

```
dbms_output.put_line(‘We’ve earned’||sumofearning);
```

With this line:

```
dbms_output.put_line('We’ve earned'||sumofearning);
```

Comment: Thanks for help! :)
Unfortunately now it shows another problem:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the f ollowing: if

Answer (score 0):

`if` statement in `PLSQL` should end with `end if`;
After `DBMS_OUTPUT` try below

```
END IF;
END;
/
```

This should work.